# Timestamps showing as 1970 in QuestDB when writing from node.js

Tags: questdb

I have a table that looks like:

| timestamp | sensor | reading |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ts1 | sensor name | 123 |

The main part of my script where I'm writing data looks like the following:

```js
const run = async () => {
  try {
    const client = new Client({
      database: "qdb",
      ...
    })
    await client.connect()
    // read sensors
    ...
    const insertData = await client.query(
      "INSERT INTO measurements VALUES($1, $2, $3);",
      [Date.now(), sensor_id, sensor_reading],
    )
    await client.query("COMMIT")

    await client.end()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

run()
```

The sensor ID and measurements are looking fine, but the timestamps are all 1970, what's wrong with the date insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuestDB has microsecond resolution timestamp natively. `Date.now()` creates a millisecond-resolution timestamp.

If you don't mind the loss of precision, you can just multiply by 1000:

```js
    const insertData = await client.query(
      "INSERT INTO measurements VALUES($1, $2, $3);",
      [Date.now() * 1000, sensor_id, sensor_reading],
    )
```

If you have high-throughput or a need for accuracy, you can use the microtime package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/microtime